# how to insert linked list nodes in multiple functions without using global variables in c++?

Tags: c++, global, code-cleanup, clean-architecture

```
struct MonthReservationsAverage
{
    string monthName;
    int averageOfReservations;
    MonthReservationsAverage *link;
};


void getMonthReferenceAndCalculateAverage()
{
    const string monthsReferencesFile = "months_files_names.txt";
    ifstream inputFile(monthsReferencesFile);
    string monthReference;
    MonthReservationsAverage *firstMonthAverage,
        *lastMonthAverage, *newMonthAverage;
    firstMonthAverage = NULL;
    lastMonthAverage = NULL;

    while (getline(inputFile, monthReference))
    {

        newMonthAverage = new MonthReservationsAverage;
        ifstream monthInputFile(monthReference);
        int reservationsAveragForMonth;
        int totalReservationsOfmonthCounter = 0;
        int dailyReservations;
        int daysOfMonthCounter = 0;

        while (!monthInputFile.eof())
        {

            monthInputFile >> dailyReservations;
            totalReservationsOfmonthCounter += dailyReservations;
            daysOfMonthCounter++;
        }
        monthInputFile.close();

        reservationsAveragForMonth = totalReservationsOfmonthCounter / daysOfMonthCounter;
        newMonthAverage->monthName = monthReference.substr(0, 3);
        newMonthAverage->averageOfReservations = reservationsAveragForMonth;
        newMonthAverage->link = NULL;

        if (firstMonthAverage == NULL)
        {
            firstMonthAverage = newMonthAverage;
            lastMonthAverage = newMonthAverage;
        }
        else
        {
            lastMonthAverage->link = newMonthAverage;
            lastMonthAverage = newMonthAverage;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    writeInfoInTextMode(firstMonthAverage);
}
```

hello everyone, I'm working with linked lists, I wrote this piece of logic, it works OK, but the problem is that the **getMonthReferenceAndCalculateAverage** is responsible of doing more than one thing, and that's not too good, so can anyone help me to divide this logic into more than one function without using global variables ?

I'm thinking of inserting nodes in different function, but the problem is how shall the linked list append the new node?

Comment: Pass a pointer/reference to the head of the linked list as parameter. Or turn your linked list into a proper class with member functions

Comment: how about iterators?

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks a lot for your time, but I didn't understand your first suggestion, so kindly if you can explain it more you will make my day, and regarding to using classes, to be honest, this is a home work in functional programming ;)

Comment: @KrzysztofMochocki thanks for your time, but the answer must be with linked lists, cuz it's a home work ;)

Comment: You can pass either a `MonthReservationsAverage*` or a `MonthReservationsAverage&` as parameter to a function. That is very basic C++ knowledge (which you should have been taught before learning about functional programming in the language)